# getting error while uploading image to cloudinary using multer and nodejs

Tags: node.js, multer, cloudinary

I am facing error while uploading video in cloudinary with nodejs . I am getting error `{ message: 'Invalid image file', name: 'Error', http_code: 400 }` ,even I am uploading .mp4 file or video file I am still getting error . I tried with image configuration uploading image and it is successfully getting uploaded .I am using multer library for this

I tried uploading different size video and different extension and I already filtering file with mimetype "video/mp4" and I tried to copy and paste the code of tutorial but still no luck ,getting error and I tried to search the web and chatgpt but no luck. Hope good people and members of stack overflow help me .

Thank you in advance :)

My multer config file :

```
const multer = require("multer");
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const fileExt = file.originalname.split(".").pop();
    const filename = `${new Date().getTime()}.${fileExt}`;
    cb(null, filename);
    },
    });
    const imageFileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (!file.mimetype.startsWith("image")) {
    cb("Supports only image files!", false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
    };
    
    const videoFileFilter=(req, file, cb) => {
    // if (!file.mimetype.startsWith("video")) {
    //   cb("Supports only video files!", false);
    // }
      if(file.mimetype!=="video/mp4"){
        cb("Supports only video files!", false);
      }
    
      cb(null, true);
    
    };
    
    exports.uploadImage = multer({ storage, fileFilter:imageFileFilter });
        exports.uploadVideo = multer({ storage, fileFilter:videoFileFilter});
        


my router file :
`router.post('/upload-trailer',uploadVideo.single('trailer'),uploadTrailer);`

my controller file :

`exports.uploadTrailer = async (req, res,next) => {
    const { file } = req;
    console.log(file)
    try{
        if (!file) return sendError(res, "Video file is missing!");
      
        const { secure_url: url, public_id } = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
          file.path,
          {
            resource_type: "video",
          }
        );
        res.status(201).json({ url, public_id });
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error)
        next(error)
    }
  };`




file or video info 

connected to database successfully
`{
  fieldname: 'trailer',
  originalname: 'pexels-pressmaster-9034146-1920x1080-25fps.mp4',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'video/mp4',
  destination: 'C:\\Users\\Mahir\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
  filename: '1685539421329.mp4',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Mahir\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1685539421329.mp4',
  size: 6087806
}`
```

attaching postman screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error response you're receiving it looks like you are uploading the file as an image. Can you try and force it as a video and maybe take a second look at your conditional?

Comment: actually i am uploading video in mp4 format . let me show you the screenshot,attached the screenshot @Pixelcook

Comment: yes exactly this, `Invalid image file'` is usually when you have resource_type set to `image` in your API call but sending a non-image file.

Comment: resource_type is set to video ,you can see the code

Comment: @mahir yes in your sample it's set to video but it looks like somehow it's not using that because the only way that error happens is if you send non image files to image endpoint. I would doublecheck your routing and also make sure to use the latest node.js SDK. This may help too: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_and_video_upload#node_js_video_upload

Comment: i tried everything and no luck ,I really dont know what to do , I tried to search on youtube but there is nothing on there related to video upload

Comment: can you upload your project to codesandbox.io or similar where I can replicate?